# cannot use tortoisesvn svadmin hotcopy command

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

I've installed TortoiseSVN, CollabNet Subversion Client, and Subversion onto my Windows 7 computer and created my first repository, locally. I am a single user, the only programmer in a company with 8 employees. I had hoped to completely avoid the SVN CLI but it seems it needs to use the 'svnadmin hotcopy' command in order to correctly back up my repository. The problem is my CLI doesn't recognize any SVN commands. I know I'm just a newbie but TortoiseSVN has otherwise made my life so much better. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The problem is my CLI doesn't recognize any SVN commands" - what is the error message? Have you tried to reinstall your SVN command line client? Is environmental path set correctly?

Comment: @Ivan Jovovic: Yes I did reinstall the SVN CLI client and it didn't work. I tried it again to show you the error message I got, and it did work. I suppose I needed to reboot before it worked. I tried the 'svnadmin hotcopy' command and, my initial guess is that it didn't like the spaces in my file path. I have no ideal what an environmental path is nor do I know how to see it  or set it. I've been doing LabVIEW for so long that I don't remember any of that any more.